# Full width submenu with sticky nav

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, submenu, sticky

I'm trying to incorporate a submenu into a sticky navigation that displays full width on drop down. Right now I can only get the submenu to display the width of the parent element and not the full width like the nav menu. I am essentially trying to create the menu functionality used on this site: http://munchies.vice.com/en

I have a placeholder dropdown under the "watch" section of my site (here: http://interactive.wttw.com/foodphiles) that is using this function to display the dropdown:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
      /* This is the function that will get executed after the DOM is fully loaded */
      function () {
        /* Next part of code handles hovering effect and submenu appearing */
        $('.navElement').hover(
          function () { //appearing on hover
            $('.submenu', this).fadeIn();
          },
          function () { //disappearing on hover
            $('.submenu', this).fadeOut();
          }
        );
      }
    );
</script>
```

Moving the submenu out of the containing div to get it to display 100% based on the navigation width works only in that it displays full width but breaks everything else. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the width using .css({width:'400'})
Obviously change 400 to whatever the width of the navElement is. Let me know if this helps or if you need alternate methods.

Comment: Yep. Problem with that is that it doesn't expand with the browser window correctly. I need the subnav to span full-width no matter the window width, just like the navigation.

Comment: Okay I'll look into other ideas, just to get things straight though, in your css for the class submenu (.submenu) have you set display to "inline-block"?

Comment: if possible, can you add your navigation, css and script to JSFiddle?

Comment: I do have it set to inline-block, thanks.